# Typescript - How to pass function pointer into function and call within function body

Tags: typescript, function-pointers

I am trying to pass a function pointer into an existing function in Typescript. The below should work, but when calling `agreet()` I receive undefined, why?

```
function greeter(greetFuncPtr) {
  console.log(greetFuncPtr); // returns ƒ () { greet(); }
  console.log(greetFuncPtr()); // returns undefined
  console.log(greet()); // returns "Hello"
  return greetFuncPtr();
}

function greet() {
  return "Hello";
}


document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = greeter(() => { greet(); });
```

See fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/17w246uz/

Comment: Just pass `greet`. `greeter(greet)`

Comment: You not return anything => {return ...}

Comment: @Estradiaz yes right you are! A bit of blind sight. Funnily enough I did it right in the JS Console in Chrome :/ 
Long day...

Comment: @tkausl thanks, that's much neater

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you use in the arrow function implies that the result of `greet` is not returned by the arrow function, to return it you would need to use a `return`

```
function greeter(agreet: () => string) { 
    console.log(agreet); // returns ƒ () { greet(); }
    console.log(agreet()); // returns undefined
    console.log(greet()); // returns "Hello"
    return agreet();
}

function greet() {
    return "Hello";
}


greeter(() => { return greet() });
```

Or not use the `{}`:

```
greeter(() => greet());
```

Or pass the function directly :

```
greeter(greet);
```

**Note** The type I added to `agreet` would have prevented the error in the first place, since you would have gotten an error that the passed in arrow function returned `void` instead of `string`

Answer (score 1):

In the arrow function you pass by calling `greeter(() => {greet()})`, you are missing a `return` statement. Hence, it returns `undefined`.

The simple fix is to a) add a `return` statement, or b) remove the curly brackets:

```js
function greeter(agreet) {
  return agreet();
}

function greet() {
  return "Hello";
}


console.log(greeter(() => {return greet()}));
console.log(greeter(() => greet()));
```